# For loop doesn't iterate over the whole dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this code:

```
print(df)

c = 900
count = 1
for i in df['Timestamp']:
    if df['Timestamp'][i] >= c:
        c+=900
        count+=1

print('candles', count)
print(c)
```

It prints this

```
        Timestamp    A Bid    A Ask    B Bid    B Ask  Spread 1  Spread 2
0               0  1.22365  1.22371  1.22360  1.22374      11.0       9.0
1               0  1.22365  1.22371  1.22358  1.22369      13.0       4.0
2               0  1.22365  1.22371  1.22356  1.22368      15.0       3.0
3               0  1.22365  1.22371  1.22355  1.22367      16.0       2.0
4               1  1.22361  1.22363  1.22355  1.22367       8.0       6.0
...           ...      ...      ...      ...      ...       ...       ...
148167      55791  1.22233  1.22237  1.22227  1.22239      10.0       6.0
148168      55791  1.22233  1.22237  1.22226  1.22239      11.0       6.0
148169      55791  1.22235  1.22237  1.22226  1.22239      11.0       4.0
148170      55792  1.22233  1.22237  1.22226  1.22239      11.0       6.0
148171      55793  1.22233  1.22236  1.22226  1.22239      10.0       6.0

[148172 rows x 7 columns]

candles  37
33300
```

So basically, the largest timestamp is 55793. So there should be 61 candles cause 55793 / 900 ~ 61.
But for some reason the for loop stops when c=33300 even though there are clearly bigger values. So what's the problem here?

Comment: Why double for loop?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: That's probably because your `if df['Timestamp'][i] >= c:` is not always `True`. You should see the expected value if you place your `c+=900` outside the `if` part.

Comment: The latest c value saved is 33300. But we can see that the latest timestamp is larger than that, So  if df['Timestamp'][i] >= c: should probably return true and the latest c value should be ~55000

Comment: If you print ```df['Timestamp][333000]``` does it print 55793?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, look at the *for* statement **carefully**. You will notice that you are using `for i in df['Timestamp']` and **not** something like `for i in range(len(df['Timestamp']))`. This means that you are **iterating through the items directly** in the `df['Timestamp']` and not via the **index** of the items.

So, when you do something like `df['Timestamp'][i]` within the if statement, what essentially happens is that it returns the value of the timestamp located in i<sup>th</sup> index. This means that at the last iteration of for loop:

```
# Last item of df['Timestamp']
i = 55793

# Item (timestamp) at index 55793
df['Timestamp'][i] = 33300
```

You would have have got an *Error* if the timestamps were not of type **int**

### Simple Fix:

Replace the line `if df['Timestamp'][i] >= c` with `if i >= c`. Also providing a variable name other than `i` would reduce the chances of mistaking `i` for index.

---

Hope this gives you an insight of what's happening in this code snippet :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you use `i` as an index (should go up to 148171) while you get it from the values (so it is limited to 55793).

What you wanted is probably:

```
for i in range(len(df)):
    if df['Timestamp'][i] >= c:
        c+=900
        count+=1
```

This would be slightly more pandas idiomatic:

```
for i, t in df['Timestamp'].items():
    if t >= c:
        c += 900
        count += 1
```